# Сборка QtCreator на windows 10

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator, mingw, сборка

Скачал исходники Qt Creator
[image: Исходник Qt Creator]
Успешно собрал с помощью команд:

```
qmake path_to_source\qtcreator.pro
mingw32-make -j4
```

После при запуске qtcreator.exe, получаю ошибки :

> Отсутствие файлов:
>
> ```
> Qt5Network.dll
> Qt5Gui.dll
> Qt5Core.dll
> Qt5Widgets.dll
> ```

Что бы исправить это, копирую созданные папки `lib`, `bin`, `share` в папку, где установлен Qt, с заменой файлов.

Дальше ругается на отсутствие файлов:

```
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
```

Закинул в папку `C:/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin`, где лежит собранный creator. После этого возникает такие ошибки:
[image: err1]
[image: err2]
[image: err3]
И сейчас у меня возникло подозрение, что я делаю что то не так. Помогите!

Comment: А действовать по [инструкции](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator#compiling-qt-and-qt-creator-on-windows)  не пробовали? Есть сильное подозрение, что и Qt надо собирать тем же mingw, чтобы библиотеки успешно линковались.

Answer (score 2):

Наверное надо сделать установку, как положено:

```
mingw32-make install INSTALL_ROOT=$INSTALL_DIRECTORY
```

Comment: и куда он установит?

Comment: наверное ничего не изменилось в плане ошибок

Comment: надо указать путь, например: mingw32-make install INSTALL_ROOT=/Qt/MyQtCreator, я в линуксе собирал, всё заработало

Comment: спасибо за пояснение, но увы. Сейчас ввел `mingw32-make install INSTALL_ROOT=C:\QT\Tools\QtCreatorMinGW`. Все установил, вот только ничего не изменилось.Ему все так же не хватает файлов, которые писал выше. Когда даю ему, он говорит: точка входа не найдена

Comment: может нужно какую то стороннюю библиотеку установить? Например для сборки нужен был питон(забыл в описание установки добавить).